# Django - how to use kwargs

Tags: python, django

I'm overriding the `.save()` method of a django model and I'm trying to pass an extra argument when saving:

View:

```
def form_valid(self, form):    
    response = super(DeliveryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)    
    self.object.save(owner=self.request.user)
    return response
```

In the .save()

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):              
    owner = kwargs.pop('owner', None)
```

My problem is that owner always comes empty. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `owner` comes empty or `owner` is not in `kwargs`?

Comment: Is that what you really have in `save()`? Because `owner` is a local variable that will disappear when `save()` returns. Don't you mean `self.owner = ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a standard create or update view, the superclass `form_valid` will already be calling the model save method, via the form. You'll either need to deal with that situation, or don't call super.

Comment: You are right. I managed to pass the argument but as you said the .save() is being called twice.